Black screen on Ubuntu 22.04 after booting without upgrades
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on an MSI motherboard with an ASUS GeForce GT 730 2GB DDR3 BRK EVO graphics card I bought six months ago. Until last Friday everything was good, and I could plug in two screens. This Monday the screens are completely black.
I thought the CMOS battery might be down, so I changed it with a couple of spare ones in the office (although they were not brand new), but the problem was still there (plus, I think there is an error code on the screen when the CMOS battery is down).
I have seen there are several occurrences of this problem on the web, but I have not upgraded the system. I can't run the terminal or other features because there is completely nothing on the screen. I can't even enter the booting system. So far the only things I know are working are the fans.
What might be the problem? The CMOS battery? The graphic card? The OS?

It depends on when you get black screen, if you do not get POSt then there is something wrong/fried in your computer and you should look in hardware forums instead, If you come to Grub but can not go further then the problem can be OS, You can try booting from Ubuntu USB and try Ubuntu, please read askubuntu.com/help/on-topic and do some searches when you know more.

I am more on the first category: at booting there is absolutely nothing...
